# Find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^n\cdot n!}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{4n+3}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the set of integers $S = \{2^0.0!, 2^1.1!, 2^2.2!, \ldots \}$. What do we get when we sum its series of reciprocals? Answer the same question for set $S' =\{3, 7, 11, 15, 19, \ldots \}$.

I try to use the series, $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = e - 1 \ \ \text{and}\ \ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = 1$$ Should I have to show that the series diverges or converges?

I get the original series, sum of reciprocals of $S < 2e$, so it should converge. I am not sure my answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Notice that for the first that  $$e^{1/2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n n!}$$

Use the [Comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) to the second to see it diverges.

$$4n + 3 < 4n + 4$$